# How can I save form data on MailChimp with custom fields

Tags: jquery, node.js, api, mailchimp

I've tried below code and it is saving the form fields to list depending upon which list id I have provided .

```
var mcReq = {
    apikey: 'bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx5dxf-us14',
    id: 'af0934ac6ea7',
    email: { email: 'abkumar@erere.com' },
    merge_vars: {
        FNAME: 'abhishek',
        LNAME: 'kumar'
    },
    double_optin: false,
    send_welcome: true
}
```

What I want is something like this:

1. I want custom fields
2. I want to save the text data on one fields and object on another
      field something like this,

   ```
   "columns" : [
       {
           id: 3232,
           "cParentCss" : {
               "text-align" : "center"
           },
           "css" : {
               "margin-top" : "0px"
           }
       }
   ]
   ```

How can I achieve this?

Suppose I have three fields say email, id, data and its data format will be `abc@gmail.com ,123, {name:'vikrant',age:28,sex:'male'}` respectively.

Comment: Hi @Vikrant, You don't want your api key exposed,
Could you be more specific with your question? Did you created custom fields on your lists for this?